# XslCompiledTransform.Transform: pass a list of strings as input parameter and check "input array contains"

Tags: c#, xslt

How to pass a list of strings in **XslCompiledTransform.Transform**  method and check inside xsl document condition like "input array contains some attribute of xml node"? I know that I can pass a string but how to parse it? What if I want to pass 1000 strings?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you want to ckeck? Are you looking for the value of a certain attribute to be contained in the array? Or for the name of an attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you have two options, if you want to compare the value in XSLT/XPath you would need to build an XML document with the strings and you can compare `foo/@bar = $param/strings/string`. As an alternative, you can implement an extension object to which you pass the attribut value or name from XSLT and then you do the comparison in your .NET code.

Comment: In the 1st option do you mean that I can join xml with array and xml which is needed to transform?

Comment: You can easily create an XML document from a an array of strings and pass that document in as a parameter.